# When does QObject custom property get initialized from value specified in stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt

I have following user defined property in my `MyWidget` class

```
Q_PROPERTY(QColor HighlightColor READ GetHighlightColor WRITE SetHighlightColor USER true);
```

And I set the property value in my application level stylesheet

```
MyWidget
{
    qproperty-HighlightColor:#121212;
}
```

I want to get the color value specified in the stylesheet in `MyWidget` constructor with `GetHighlightColor()` but I don't get the correct value. I had to start a single shot timer with a short time interval in the constructor and call `GetHighlightColor()` when the timer fires to get the correctly set value.

So when does the property initialization take place? What is earliest possible point which I can access the property value which is initialized with value in stylesheet?

Comment: I'm guessing it could be when the widget gets shown. You could try to call [`QWidget::ensurePolished`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#ensurePolished) before you call `getHighlightColor` and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work

Comment: Well I tested calling `ensurePolished` and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested calling [`QWidget::ensurePolished`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#ensurePolished) after creating the widget, and calling `getHighlightColor` after that gave me the correct `QColor`.

*main.cpp*

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setStyleSheet("MyWidget{qproperty-highlightColor:#ff0000;}");
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
mw = new MyWidget(this);
mw->ensurePolished();
qDebug() << mw->getHighlightColor();
```

*Output*

```
QColor(ARGB 1, 1, 0, 0)
```